# Why is my margin going on the entire div?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with one div and 1 H1 tag in the div;

I am giving a margin to a H1 and it's giving the margin the the entire div

Why is this?

http://craveadeal.com/indexV2.php

Here is the entire code:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-image: url(image-files/mockupV2.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 555px;
 width: 1040px;
 background-position: center top;
}
#wrapper h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 72px;
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
 text-decoration: blink;
 color: #F07D00;
 background-color: #000;
 margin-right: 125px;
 margin-left: 125px;
 display: block;
 margin-top: 125px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper"><h1>COMING SOON</h1>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This isn't happening when I view the page; what browser is displaying the issue? Can you please post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `overflow:hidden` to the `#wrapper`

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem**

It's being caused by [margin collapse](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins):

> "In this specification, the expression
>   collapsing margins means that
>   adjoining margins of two or more boxes
>   combine to form a single margin."

Or more simply:

> when the vertical margins of two
>   elements are touching, only the margin
>   of the element with the largest margin
>   value will be honored, while the
>   margin of the element with the smaller
>   margin value will be collapsed to
>   zero.

**The Solution**

You can fix it by:

1. Adding vertical padding to your  `#wrapper`.
2. Adding a border to your `#wrapper`.
3. Floating your `<h1>`.